# What is the difference between ts-node and tsc

Tags: typescript

I am new to Typescript and came across ts-node and tsc, that is, if we install ts-node, is tsc included by default inside ts-node since as far as I know, ts-node understands Typescript and runs it directly

Answer (score 12):

`tsc` is the TypeScript compiler, which is completely separate from `ts-node`.

`ts-node` is a wrapper for Node.js's `node` executable that installs a TypeScript-enabled module loader that compiles TypeScript on the fly as needed. From [its `npm` page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node):

> TypeScript Node works by registering the TypeScript compiler for `.tsx?` and `.jsx?` (when `allowJs` == true) extensions. When node.js has an extension registered (via require.extensions), it will use the extension internally for module resolution.

`ts-node` uses `tsc` by default, but can use other compilers if you specify the `--compiler` option.

Comment: so, ts-node kinda has its own compiler and we can use either ts-node or tsc, if so, which is used when? for example for development and production. Thank you

Comment: @Sukich - No, `ts-node` is not a compiler. It *uses* a compiler. `ts-node` is useful for when you want to have a tool (`ts-node`) handle compiling your Node.js-based TypeScript for you on-the-fly. `tsc` is useful any other time you want to compile TypeScript to JavaScript -- because you don't want to do that at runtime on Node.js, or because you're not using Node.js at all (compiling to JavaScript for another environment, such as a web browser).